# C - going from ncurses ui to external program and back

Tags: c, ncurses, external-process

I'm making a program that displays some info in ncurses, and then opens vim (using `system`) to allow the user to edit a file.  After vim is exited, though, the ncurses screen won't redraw.  `refresh` and `wrefresh` don't do anything, resulting in the complete trashing of my beautiful menu.

So, I get sent back to the command line.  The menu items redraw when I move to them.  Moving around a bit results in something that looks like this:

[image: Tragedy]

As you can see, I no longer am in my pretty ncurses environment,.

I could tear down ncurses completely and set things up again, but then some stuff (like menu position) is not preserved.

How do I do this correctly?  Is there a better way to call some external program and return here gracefully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never had to restart curses entirely.

what if you do something like

[def_prog_mode()](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcurses/def_prog_mode.html) then
[endwin()](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcurses/endwin.html)

execute system call

and refresh() should restore it

Comment: Thanks!  This seems to work, but every now and then I get back to my curses UI and none of my keystrokes register.  So I have to kill the program.  Any ideas?

Comment: how do you init ncurses?

    initscr();      /* initialize the curses library */
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);  /* enable keyboard mapping */
    nonl();         /* tell curses not to do NL->CR/NL on output */
    cbreak();       /* take input chars one at a time, no wait for \n */
    noecho();       /* don't echo input */

Is something changing the input method? you could call cbreak() when you return

Comment: I'm doing all the above, still no luck unfortunately.

Comment: This seems similar to the problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189708/ncurses-to-external-shell-and-back-messing-with-keys  But calling keypad(win, 1) doesn't help.

Comment: sorry flat out of ideas for loss of keystrokes

Answer (score 0):

Separate your program state from the curses state.

The only clean way I know of is to stop and restart curses entirely.  If your program has a clean notion of its internal state (as it should), then it should be easy to go back to the same position.

Good luck!